# Safari distorts content in element with position fixed and transform matrix

Tags: css, safari

I realized all the content in an element with styles `position: fixed` and `transform: matrix` is distorted and no solution I can find so far, of course, besides changing the `position` to other than `fixed`.

Tested on `Safari v10.1.2`

And here is an image:
[image]

Here are the html:

```
<div class="first fixed">
    Fixed element  
</div>

<div class="second ">
   Static element
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.first {
  background: steelblue;
  transform: matrix(3, 0, 0, 3, 300, 100); /* Standard syntax */
}

div.second {
  background: orange;
  transform: matrix(3, 0, 0, 3, 300, 250); /* Standard syntax */
}

.fixed {
  position:fixed;
}
```

And demo: http://jsbin.com/woboyifiko/edit?html,css,output